# Unable to load GLTF object

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I'm attempting to render a GLTF model with three.js but have been unable to do so. If anyone could pinpoint what the error in my code is, I'd be glad.

```
        import {GLTFLoader} from "./GLTFLoader.js";

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            75,
            window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,
            .01,
            1000
        );
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

        loader.load("scene.gltf",function(gltf){
            var obj;
            scene.add(gltf.scene);
        });
        var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xFFFFFF, 0x000000, 2);
        scene.add(light);
        camera.position.set(0,0,100);
        function animate(){
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene,camera);
        }
        animate();
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the glTF asset in this thread?

Comment: Sorry, it was this one: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/free-lamborghini-aventador-sv-tunnig-by-sdc-4350c8de8fd740f582bd316c1fa010ff

Comment: The model loads without issues in the three.js editor. Please verify if no runtime error appears in the browser console. Also consider to share your entire code as a live example (e.g. codesandbox) or as a GitHub repository.

Comment: Doesn't seem to load for me in the editor. Is it as simple as clicking import and loading scene.gltf?

Comment: You have to drag/drop all the asset components (.gltf + .bin + textures).

Answer (score 3):

First you can download the free 3d model gltf file from sketchfab and then convert it into glb format using [this website](https://sbtron.github.io/makeglb/). Then compress the file with:

`npx gltf-pipeline -i scene.glb -o model.glb --draco.compressionLevel=10`

By using:

`npx gltfjsx model.glb`

You will get a js file. Just copy the model function and * boom! * your work will be done. For an example, you can refer [visit demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/floating-shoe-forked-qxjoj).

Answer (score 0):

First check your browser's console, (shortcut generally ctrl+shift+i), if there's an error there, the path could be wrong, also you could `console.log(gltf)` to see if the object really loaded in your "onload" function, if it logs `undefined`, there's probably an error.

It could also be that your model is too big and not rendering (it's outside of your camera render area) or it's your camera that's inside of it and all the object faces are pointing outwards (inward faces are culled by default in some materials, it's called back-face culling).
To test this in your mesh, you can add inside your "onload" function:

```js
gltf.scene.traverse(obj => {
  if (obj.type === "Mesh") {
    obj.doubleSided = true;
    // or maybe
    // obj.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
  }
})
```

This will iterate through all of the objects inside your gltf file, check which ones are meshes, and mark them as double sided, so both inwards and outwards faces will render and back-faces won't be culled.

Also check if reducing your object's scale to something like 0.1 or 0.01 makes it visible.

Comment: Thanks, I did this and noticed the error "THREE.GLTFLoader is not a constructor". I'm wondering if it has anything to do with changing the path to "./three.module.js" that I did, following the advice here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4q2cqj_Tdc&ab_channel=MikeSmith

Comment: Oh, the problem is that your script cant find the 'GLTFLoader', its a class that's not included by default in three.js, it needs to be included separately, you could also reference it with a CDN.

Instead of a local script copied and pasted, it gets the script via a cdn
just put in your html `<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="GLTFLoader.js">`